# Django - force form to save to a specific model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

**views.py**

```
class BHA_UpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = BHA_List
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk_alt'
    form_class = BHA_overall_Form
```

**forms.py**

```
class BHA_overall_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = BHA_overall
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class BHA_List(models.Model):
    well = models.ForeignKey(WellInfo, 'CASCADE', related_name='bha_list')
    bha_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class BHA_overall(models.Model):
    bha_number = models.ForeignKey(BHA_List, 'CASCADE', related_name='bha_overall')
    drill_str_name = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    depth_in = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    depth_out = models.CharField(max_length=111)
```

If I display the form fields to users using `{{ form.as_p }}` in my template, it will generate a page that looks like this:

[image]

How can I override `get()` or `post()` method to take input from the user, and save the user input, and update a specific model instance?

With my current `views.py`, user input from `forms` won't save to DB because my `form` refers to `model = BHA_overall`, where as my model for `views.py` is `model = BHA_List`. But for some reason I do not want to change my model in `views.py`.

If I change my `CBV` to `CreateView` instead of `UpdateView`, it will create a new `BHA_overall` instance to DB without any issue. But if I want to UPDATE a specific model instance of `BHA_overall`, I first need to `get()` a model instance of `BHA_overall`, and update the model instance through `post()`. But I do not know how to do this. How should I go about this?

Edit:

something like this:

```
def post():
    bha_overall_instance1.bha_number = userinput.bha_number
    bha_overall_instance1.drill_str_name = userinput.drill_str_name
    bha_overall_instance1.depth_in = userinput.depth_in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use just

```
from django.views import View
```

and your views.py:

```
from django.views import View
from django.models import Model1, Model2
class UpdateView(View):
      model = Model1
      template_name = 'update.html'

      def post(self, request, id, name , "other-parameters", ..., *kwargs):
          obj1 = self.model1.objects.get_or_404(id=id) # this just example you can past any parameters that you want
          if obj1:
             obj1.name = name # updating name of obj1
             obj1.save() # savin updated object
          obj2 = Model2.objects.get_or_404(id=request.POST.get('id') # you must to pass name='some-id' in your template at input tag
          if obj2:
             obj2.some_field = some_parameter
             obj2.save()
          return redirect('index/') # you must choose only url that exists
```

I wait your feedback